# Find the derived set of $S =\{(2/p)+(3/q) : p,q\in \mathbb N \}$ and check if that set is open.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Find the derived set of $S =\{(2/p)+(3/q) : p,q\in \mathbb N \}$ and check if that set is open.

I guess its derived set should be $D:=\{0\}\cup\{2/p: p \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{3/q : q \in \mathbb{N}\}$ but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: No, $\{0\}\cup \{\frac{2}{p}~:~p\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{\frac{3}{q}~:~q\in\Bbb N\}$ is not the same as the set $\{\frac{2}{p}+\frac{3}{q}~:~p,q\in\Bbb N\}$.  For one thing, $0$ is not an element of the set in question.  There do not exist any choices of $p,q$ such that $\frac{2}{p}+\frac{3}{q}=0$.  Next, there are elements which can be expressed as $\frac{2}{p}+\frac{3}{q}$ which can not be expressed as just $\frac{2}{p}$ or as $\frac{3}{q}$ by themselves.  For instance, $5 = \frac{2}{1}+\frac{3}{1}$

Comment: As for checking if the set is open... consider again more closely the curious case of $5$ which is as mentioned already an element of $S$.  It helps also to remind us the specific definition of "*open*" which you are using as it can vary.

Comment: No countable set can be open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The question is not about the set $S$ itself, but about the derived set $D$. Certainly $0$ is a limit point of $S$, so belongs to $D$. If $p$ is fixed and $q\to\infty$ we see that $2/p\in D$, similarly $3/q\in D.$ The question now is whether there are any other points in $D$, and the answer to that is no (ether both $p,q$ go to $\infty$ and limit point is $0$, or one is fixed and limits points are of type described above). So the OP guess is correct. Clearly the derived set is not open. (I didn't see original statement, question was edited after that,so perhaps JM comment applied?)

Comment: @mirko you'll have to define that term then I suppose.  What is a "derived set"?  Just the set of limit points?  I point again to the fact that 5 is an element of (and thus a limit point of) S but is not an element of their attempt at D.  And there are surely many more elements missing as well,  1.5 and so on, which were elements of the first but not the second

Comment: @JMoravitz I erased a previous comment in order to correct it: A limit point of $S$ is a point $x$ every neighborhood of which contains points of $S$ *different* from $x$. In other words $x$ is in the closure of $S\setminus\{x\}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point Just to clarify, for example, the set of integers has no limit points at all, and not every point of a set $S$ must be a limit point of $S$. (Points in $S$ that are not limit points are called isolated in $S$, they are isolated in the relative topology of $S$).

Answer (score 2):

The question is not about the set $S$ itself, but about the derived set $D$ (which is defined as the set of all limit points of $S$ (where, in turn, $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if $x$ is in the topological closure of $S\setminus\{x\}$)). Certainly $0$ is a limit point of $S$ (when $p,q$ both go to $\infty$), so $0$ belongs to $D$. If $p$ is fixed and $q\to\infty$ we see that $2/p\in D$, similarly $3/q\in D.$ The question now is whether there are any other points in $D$, and the answer to that is no (ether both $p,q$ go to $\infty$ in which case the limit point is $0$, or one of $p$ or $q$ is fixed and the other goes to $\infty$, and then the limit points are of the type already described above). So the OP guess is correct, $$D:=\{0\}\cup\{2/p: p \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{3/q : q \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$ Clearly the derived set is not open.